# Solution when matching on $X_1$ increases imbalance in $X_2$ and vice versa?

Tags: multiple-regression, unbalanced-classes, propensity-scores, matching, covariate-balance

My work team has come across a situation in our propensity score matching analysis where matching treatments to controls on one covariate, $X_1$, increases the imbalance in a second covariate, $X_2$, and vice versa.

An investigation of the data revealed there is little common support or overlap between the two variable's values in the matching cohorts. Akin to the treatment group containing young males and old females and the control group containing old males and young females.

How do we condition on the $X_1$ and $X_2$ variables in this case?

My first inclination is to avoid matching on $X_1$ and $X_2$. Instead, include them in the post-matching outcome regression.